# Excel VBA Range.Replace operates over entire workbook

Tags: excel, vba, replace, find

I'm having a problem with Range.Replace. As we all know, when in the Excel worksheet interface we can Find & Replace with Match Case set to True or False, and when we Find or Replace again Excel remembers our Match Case setting. The same is true if we use Find & Replace from VBA, and for other settings such as LookIn, LookAt.

Note that Find & Replace using the Excel worksheet interface also remembers the "Within" option (set to either "Sheet" or "Workbook"). My problem is that if I have used Find & Replace from the worksheet interface and I have set the "Within" option to "Workbook" (instead of the default "Sheet"), then Excel VBA also remembers that option, and does a Workbook-level Replace **even if I am invoking Range.Replace** (ie I only want the Replace to happen over a specific range).

I can reproduce as follows:

1. Create new workbook with three empty sheets.
2. In sheet 1 enter "this" in $A$1; in sheet 2 enter "that" in $A$1.
3. Do a Find for "junk" with "Within" set to "Workbook" and leave all other options unchecked and default. This will find nothing; close the dialogue.
4. In sheet 3, select a range eg $A$1:$K$10 and leave this sheet active.
5. Open the VB Editor and enter: `Selection.Replace "th","help"`.

You will find (well, I did) that **even though we are using a Range.Replace the instances of "th" on the inactive sheets 1 and 2 have been changed** -- so it seems that the "Within" choice has been remembered and the "Range" part of "Range.Replace" is being ignored.

Is there any way to override this? Or force Excel to forget the "Within" setting?

I am using Office Professional Plus 2016 on Windows 10.

Please help!

Comment: Seems like the answer is to `Find` the value first on the sheet in question, and then `Replace`.... quick Google search: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?11444-Solved-Replace-in-a-sheet-and-not-the-entire-workbook, and https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/83183-vba-replace-method-retains-within-workbook-setting

Comment: Specify all the optional parameters, you'll override the values "remembered" from the previous `Range.Find` call.

Comment: I suspect part of the problem is invoking `Range.Replace` over `Selection`.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - no I can replicate the issue without using `Selection`. I'm not sure I'd call it a bug, but since `Within` in the Find/Replace dialog is not an optional parameter, I think the VBA solution to coerce the replace to a Sheet is to do `Sheet.Range.Find` first, and then `Replace`.

Comment: @BigBen in any case, invoking `Range.Find` or `Range.Replace` without specifying the optional parameters, is begging for things to go wrong: silly as it is, these methods are literally specified to "remember" the values for these optional parameters, and to reuse them when not specified (regardless of the "Within" issue). Using `Sheet1.Cells.Find` effectly seems to "resets" the "Within" from "Workbook" to "Sheet" when I try it, hence my suspicion about `Selection`, which I hardly ever use at all.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I agree with you on the optional parameters. I replicated the issue even when specifying the `Sheet` though - i.e. doing a `Sheet3.Cells.Replace` replaced values on Sheets 1 and 2... It seems stupid to have to `Find` first but seems like the only workaround.

Comment: Well an alternative could be to dump the range into an array, iterate & update that array, then dump the modified array back onto the worksheet.

Comment: That is a good option, yeah.

Comment: Thanks for all this -- I will mark @BigBen 's answer as accepted. I agree with all that people have said -- I always specify all of the optional parameters for Find and Replace in VBA, and I never use Selection (I used it solely for the example because it is easier to type into the immediate window). In fact, I nearly always follow Matthieu Guidon's advice and read into memory, process the data, then write out again; but this specific case it just seemed easier to use Range.Replace. Then I spotted things changing in different sheets! Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention, Find and Replace also remembers the "Within" option, which there is no (optional) parameter for in `Range.Find` or `Range.Replace`.

If you want to absolutely guarantee that the replace is only on the `Sheet` in question, the trick then to reset the "Within" option to "Sheet" from "Workbook" is to do a `Range.Find` first, before attempting to `Range.Replace`.

Continuing with your example, the code below will only replace `th` on `Sheet1`. However, if you comment out the 2nd line, set the "Within" option to "Workbook" by replicating your 3rd step above, and then rerun this code, it will replace `th` on both `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`.

```
Sub SheetOnlyReplace()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find("Th")
    ws.Cells.Replace "th", "help", xlPart, xlByRows, False, False, False, False
End Sub
```

And because Find/Replace can be unpredictable, as this demonstrates, you could just read the values from your range into an array, iterate over it making changes, and then write the modified values back to your worksheet, as proposed by [@Mathieu Guindon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1188513/mathieu-guindon).

Comment: Thanks. It's annoying (to say the least) that I will have to use the Range.Find every time before I use Range.Replace just in case my user has just performed a Workbook find; but now that I know about it I can choose my method (I usually read into memory, process, then write, as you suggest).

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for a solution for this as well and have been able to use this article https://excel.tips.net/T008801_Changing_Default_Search_Settings.html#comment-form-hd , which basically states to reset the 'find and replace' dialog box. I also updated it to only use values.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30265011)