# Restrict .Replace to one column

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my code:

```
With WB.Sheets(1).Range("A1").EntireColumn

   .Replace What:="/", Replacement:=" & ", _
      LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
      ReplaceFormat:=False
   .Replace What:="-", Replacement:="&", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

End With
```

I've tried solutions from multiple other posts, but nothing I've tried is restricting this to just "A" or (1) if you prefer.  I've tried running the replacements both in and out of `With` blocks, but they continue to work through the whole worksheet.  I've tried `SearchOrder:=xlByColumns` & `SearchOrder:=xlByRows` as well as `.Range("$A$1:$A$ & LastRow)` but it just keeps working the whole sheet.

Comment: If you pull up the Find & Replace dialogue with Ctrl+F, is the Within option set to "Workbook" by chance?

Comment: It is!  Is there a way to switch that off with code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51712783/9245853. Or perform the replacement in memory with a `Variant` array.

Comment: @BigBen This is still looking through all columns.  I see nothing that restricts it to column "A"

Comment: `Dim rng1 As Range: Set rng1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells.Find("/")
   WB.Cells.Replace "/", "&", xlPart, xlByRows, False, False, False, False
Dim rng2 As Range: Set rng2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells.Find("-")
   WB.Cells.Replace "/", "&", xlPart, xlByRows, False, False, False, False`

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A:A").Replace` instead of `WB.Cells.Replace`.

Comment: Thanks @BigBen !! That solved it.
`Dim rng1 As Range: Set rng1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A:A").Find("/")

   ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A:A").Replace "/", "&", xlPart, xlByRows, False, False, False, False

Dim rng2 As Range: Set rng2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A:A").Find("-")

   ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A:A").Replace "/", "&", xlPart, xlByRows, False, False, False, False`